# How to show helper text / hint / label under product attributes in magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, adminhtml, product-grid

I want to show some helping text under custom product attributes in the product grid in adminhtml. Is this possible?
Thanks for guidance!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found it:
You have to set the column 'note' in the eav_attribute table.
e.g.

```sql
UPDATE eav_attribute SET note='Only characters allowed' WHERE attribute_code='my_attribute_code';
```